# Using Both Map and List for Same Objects

Tags: c++, list, c++11, iterator, unordered-map

I'm trying to use both a list and an unordered_map to store the same set of objects. I'm new to C++, so still getting comfortable with iterators.

Say I have the following test code:

```
class Test {
public:
    int x;
    int y;
    int z;
    Test (int, int, int);
}

Test t1 = Test(1,2,3);
Test t2 = Test(2,4,6);
Test t3 = Test(3,6,9);

std::list<Test> list;
std::unordered_map<int, Test> map;

list.push_back(t3);
list.push_back(t2);
list.push_back(t1);
map[101] = t1;
map[102] = t2;
map[103] = t3;
```

Is it possible to look up an object by key, and then generate a list iterator from the reference of the object (or from the unordered_map generator?)

So if I have the key 102, I could look up t2 in constant time. I then want to iterate forward/backward/insert/delete relative to t2's position in the list.

I can use find to get a unordered_map iterator pointing to t2. I don't know how to generate a list iterator that starts at t2 (I can only generate iterators at the beginning or the end of the list, and iterate through.)

Would appreciate anyone pointing me to good tutorials on the STL and iterators.

Thanks!

Afterthought:
Is this an acceptable approach? I have many objects and need to efficiently look them up by integer key. I also need to preserve their order (unrelated to these integer keys) and insert/delete/traverse efficiently.

Comment: Both the list and map store *instance* of the class, and neither can store the same instance, just copies. You need to resort to pointers if you want both the list and the map to store the exactly same instance.

Comment: Yeah, that was the intention. So if I look up the reference to my Test instance using the map, how can I find out where in the list this reference is and get the previous or next list element? Can I remove this reference from the list in constant time?

Comment: In C, I would implement a doubly-linked list, and then have a hash map pointing to elements of this doubly linked list. What is the C++ equivalent?

Comment: No, you cant remove an arbitrary node from a list in constant time, unless you have an iterator to the node in the list.

Comment: I see. Sounds the solution below is what I'm looking for. I'm surprised this doesn't come up more often (usually a sign I'm approaching the problem wrong). For this to work for me, I'll need to store pointers to iterators, so that all structures "remembering" an iterator location can be updated when I change move the data in the list. Also sounds like implementing/managing a doubly linked list by hand is preferable?

Comment: Have you looked at [Boost.MultiIndex](http://www.boost.org/libs/multi_index/)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While Barry's approach is good, there is another one, more advanced and complicated. You can put your data object, (integer) key, and all bookkeeping bits in a single chunk of memory. Thus data locality will be improved and pressure on memory allocator will be less. Example, using `boost::intrusive`:

```
#include <boost/intrusive/list.hpp>
#include <boost/intrusive/unordered_set.hpp>
#include <array>

using namespace boost::intrusive;

class Foo {
    // bookkeeping bits
    list_member_hook<> list_hook;
    unordered_set_member_hook<> set_hook;

    const int key;
    // some payload...

public:
    // there is even more options to configure container types
    using list_type = list<Foo, member_hook<Foo, list_member_hook<>, &Foo::list_hook>>;
    using set_type = unordered_set<Foo, member_hook<Foo, unordered_set_member_hook<>, &Foo::set_hook>>;

    Foo(int key): key(key) {};
    bool operator ==(const Foo &rhs) const {
        return key == rhs.key;
    }
    friend std::size_t hash_value(const Foo &foo) {
        return std::hash<int>()(foo.key);
    }
};

class Bar {
    Foo::list_type list;

    std::array<Foo::set_type::bucket_type, 17> buckets;
    Foo::set_type set{Foo::set_type::bucket_traits(buckets.data(), buckets.size())};

public:
    template<typename... Args>
    Foo &emplace(Args&&... args) {
        auto foo = new Foo(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
        // no more allocations
        list.push_front(*foo);
        set.insert(*foo);
        return *foo;
    }
    void pop(const Foo &foo) {
        set.erase(foo);
        list.erase(list.iterator_to(foo));
        // Lifetime management fun...
        delete &foo;
    }
};

int main() {
    Bar bar;
    auto &foo = bar.emplace(42);
    bar.pop(foo);
}
```

Measure how good are both algorithms on your data. My idea may give you nothing but greater code complexity.

Answer (score 5):

If what you want to do is this:

> Is it possible to look up an object by key, and then generate a list iterator from the reference of the object (or from the unordered_map generator?)

Then you can take advantage of the fact that `list` iterators aren't invalidated on insertion or erase (unless you erase that particular iterator) and reorganize your structures like this:

```
std::list<Test> list;
std::unordered_map<int, std::list<Test>::iterator> map;

map.insert(std::make_pair(101, 
    list.insert(list.end(), t1)));
map.insert(std::make_pair(102, 
    list.insert(list.end(), t2)));
map.insert(std::make_pair(103, 
    list.insert(list.end(), t3)));
```

That way your map lookup gives you exactly what you want: a `list` `iterator`.

Comment: Thanks. This is really clever. Is this the ideal way of storing locations in a list? I may want to mark certain points in a list in other maps or other data structure. So then, whenever I insert an element into the list, I'll store this iterator down in various places? It feels a bit hacky. If I look up an iterator using the map, then I move an element of the list at this location to some other place in the list, then I store the iterator at that location into my map?

Comment: @user2411693 Ideal? I don't know. It's definitely not a hack - if you want to store iterators, you have to store iterators. Anytime you manipulate the list, yeah, you'll have to make sure the map stays in line. Best way would be to wrap this in a class that controls `erase()` and `insert()`.

Comment: Thanks! I'll wait a little to see if someone has a better approach for me before marking as correct. I'm leaning towards manually implementing a doubly-linked list into my Test class, since I can then have these lookup structures just point directly to the objects (as opposed to updating each of them whenever I move something or having them store pointers to iterators).