# C++ compound data structure with unordered_map and list

Tags: c++, data-structures, stl, unordered-map

EDIT:  On closer inspection, [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28388487/using-both-map-and-list-for-same-objects) answers mine pretty well.  Especially Barry's answer.

I have a composite type like this:

```
Struct MyType 
{
    const char *UID; /* Unique key string */
    int64_t lastModified; /* essentially a timestamp */
    ... /* more data */
}
```

I want to be able to look up these objects quickly by their UID, so I have an unordered_map:

```
std::unordered_map< std::string, MyType * > uidMap;
```

I also want to operate on all the objects updated since a certain timestamp, so I have a list:

```
std::list< MyType * > updateOrder;
```

Whenever I update an object, I want to set its lastModified and move it to the front of the updateOrder.

The problem is, if I look up an object by its UID, I am holding an iterator into objMap, but not into updateOrder.  Without an iterator into updateOrder, I can't move the object to the front of the list in constant time, rather I would need to traverse the list to find it first.

It seems like I need a linked list structure where the linked list pointers are included in the object itself.  Does the STL have support for this kind of list?

Or perhaps I can use an unordered_map::iterator>.  Do I have any guarantees about how long a list::iterator will be valid?

Or is there any STL equivalent for using boost::intrusive?  That seems like it could solve my problem.

Comment: Sounds like what you need may be a variant of a boost multi-index container. http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/libs/multi_index/doc/index.html But basically you are going to need wrap two containers inside your own class that manages updates.

Comment: Unfortunately, boost is not an option.  I need either a straight STL solution, or to roll my own.